# Trying to place marquee in a precise location over an Image. Have the Image in a parent div. Within that parent div, I have the marquee div

Tags: html, css

Can not locate a div within a parent div....

I will show code below....  Have tried all the position: absolute; position: fixed; etc... in the .main the .marq and the .geek1 sections.  I copied this code from elsewhere, I am in way over my head, miracle I got this far! I am trying to get the .geek1 text to scroll across the Image just below the Last Heard in the gray area. Need the most simple solution. Thanks a lot!

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Marquee Tag</title> 
<style> 
.main { 
    text-align:center;
    width: 380px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 50px; 
} 
.marq { 
    padding-top: 1px; 
    padding-bottom:1px;
    margin-left: 20px;

} 
.geek1 { 
    font-size:11px; 
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white; 
    padding-bottom:1px; 
} 
</style> 
</head>  

<body> 
<div class = "main">
<img src="3-5_DMR_2_For_Web.jpg" width="400" height="240" alt="Natural" 
/>
<marquee class="marq" bgcolor = "636562" direction = "left" loop="" >
    <div class="geek1">2 &nbsp N &nbsp K4WZV &nbsp Robert</div> 
</marquee> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Looking for any help anyone can provide....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so but maybe z-index should help alot. I'm not sure what are you trying to do tell me where you want to put the gray area.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Marquee Tag</title> 
<style> 
.main { 
    text-align:center;
    width: 380px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 50px; 
    position: relative;
} 
img{
  vertical-align: top;
}
.marq { 
    padding-top: 1px; 
    padding-bottom:1px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
} 
.geek1 { 
    font-size:11px; 
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white; 
    padding-bottom:1px; 
} 
</style> 
</head>  

<body> 
  <div class = "main">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/14/10/54/danxia-3605276_960_720.jpg" width="400" height="240" alt="Natural" 
    />
    <marquee class="marq" bgcolor = "636562" direction = "left" loop="" >
        <div class="geek1">2 &nbsp N &nbsp K4WZV &nbsp Robert</div> 
    </marquee> 
  </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

thank you

Comment: Sara, I think you nailed it! I am tinkering with placement of the scrolling text area.  I do not understand this coding very well, but making one simple change at a time.  I changed the background color to transparent because it was overlaping text on my image. Solved that....  Now checking if this is working on major browsers. So far, so good....

Comment: Hi @MitchSavage, I am just using position on .marq and .main classes and do that in your code.